# PayPal iOS SDK doesnot work for live credentials

Tags: ios, paypal

PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: 3e8087cbf6bd1 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.2]

Configuration:

```
// Set up payPalConfig
    _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = @"en";
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"MERCHANT NAME.";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];

PayPalItem *selectedtemInfo = [PayPalItem itemWithName:productDetails
                                              withQuantity:1
                                                 withPrice:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:totalCostofProducts]
                                              withCurrency:@"USD"
                                                   withSku:nil];

PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = total;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = @Description";
    payment.items = selectedProductsItems;
    payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; 

PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                    configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                         delegate:self];
```

Comment: Don't use sandbox SIGNATURE and Email ID.....Create that from your own developer account and use it.Hope then it will work. And also set Environment as an production.

Comment: I have also got the same issue. @VibhaSingh I have used the production client id and secret key but the same error recieved.

Comment: It seems like the PayPal email address is not confirmed on your account . Can you do one thing here : Try to add a new email address in your PayPal account and then confirm it once and then try to perform the transaction once

Comment: Eshan, please look into my comments here too.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747148/issue-in-paypal-live-transaction-if-paypal-balance-is-0-00