# Issue in PayPal live transaction if PayPal Balance is $0.00

Tags: ios7, paypal, transactions

I am developing an native app for iOS 7.x having integrated PayPal iOS SDK. I am facing an issue related to live transaction via PayPal.

My PayPal account balance is $0.00 currently. My paypal account is linked to a valid credit card. I have transferred few dollar to PayPal, but the state is "Pending"

Now, I am trying to use my PayPal "Email credentials" to perform a live transaction. However, it throws me following error:

```
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: 3e8087cbf6bd1 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.2]
```

1. What can be the possible reason of this error?
2. Also is it possible to do a successful transaction when PayPal amout = $0.00, though it is linked to a valid credit card ?

Please help.

Comment: It seems like the PayPal email address is not confirmed on your account . Can you do one thing here : Try to add a new email address in your PayPal account and then confirm it once and then try to perform the transaction once .

Comment: Hi Eshan, I too had the similar issue. Email is properly configured with PayPal and I could see all the credit cards list which are configured with PayPal in my App for transaction after logged in with email from app. PayPal SDK version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the PayPal email address is not confirmed on your account . Can you do one thing here : Try to add a new email address in your PayPal account and then confirm it once and then try to perform the transaction once .

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not using the correct ClientID.  The client ID you are using is not associated with an active App from yoiur developer portal.  To correct this, please go into the [developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com) and either use a different client ID from a different 'active' app or create a new app.